# Chapter Design in Latex

Tags: sectioning, chapters, book-design

I am writing a mathematics book  for grade six . I need a special style for the title of the chapters. Does any one have an idea.
Any help is highly appreciated.
I plan to add pictures to the title.
examples of what I am working :

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titlesec, blindtext, color}
\definecolor{gray75}{gray}{0.75}
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\Huge\bfseries}{\thechapter\hsp\textcolor{gray75}{|}\hsp}{0pt}{\Huge\bfseries}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Greatest common divisor}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Example of what I see on google is the following:

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Your question tends to provoke opinion-based answers and is very broad.

Comment: You need to describe exactly what you want, and what you can/cannot currently achieve. Then users here will be able to help with the parts that are causing problems. As it stands, your question is likely to be closed, though it can be reopened if it is clarified sufficiently.

Comment: No special style I  want. I just need a simple title design appropriate for a math book for kids. For example,  The title in color with the number of chapter appeared  as a back ground. Or any other idea, this surely will help.

Comment: This site is intended for resolving specific problems. As @ChristianHupfer mentioned, the question as it stands is too broad.